# use regex to match strings containing "(number)" pattern at the end

Tags: java, regex

I use the following pattern to check if it matches with this kind of strings:

`words that contains any characters and ends with (positive numbers)`

```
assertEquals(true, str.matches("[\\w+ ]*\\(\\d\\)"));
```

the assertion returns true for the following situations:

```
str = "one two three (1)";
str = "one 2 three to 400 (4)";
str = " begins with space (4)";
str = "(4)";
```

But it fails on the following:

```
str = "one (two) three (1)";
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: "Words that contain *any* characters" also means `f882&& **&^* (4)` and `*&274p!!! (1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include parentheses in the character class -- `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` so it doesn't cover them. Also the quantifier `+` matches the literal `+` when placed in the character class, so it should be set outside the square brackets. But since you want to also match the case of `(4)`, then it should be `*` instead:

```
assertEquals(true, str.matches("[\\w ()]*\\(\\d\\)"));
```

More generally, according to your requirement *"words that contains any characters and ends with (positive numbers)"*, the following would be more suitable:

```
assertEquals(true, str.matches(".*\\(\\d\\)$"));
```

(`.` matches any character; `$` marks the end of a line)

Comment: That wouldn't match the last case "(4)" since you are using a + (1 or more) on the word character / space / parenthesis. Using * (zero or more) fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex would match *words that contain any character and end with a (positive number)*:

`.*\([1-9]+\)`

Two things to note here:

1. The regex that is provided in the original post uses `\w` which matches word characters: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
2. `\d` matches digits. This means that you regex would also match zero which is neither a positive, nor a negative number. In case you want positive numbers only then you should use `[1-9]+`